# Return value from jsonp

Tags: javascript, html

Just learning javascript & html.

I am trying to get a value from some jsonp. This is what is being returned

```
detail( {
"StatusCode": 0,
"StatusInfo": "Processed and Logged OK",
"PageNumber": 1,
"TotalPageCount": 1,
"TotalProductCount": 1,
"PageProductCount": 1,
"Products":
[
{
"BaseProductId": "57543094",
"EANBarcode": "5010204736716",
"CheaperAlternativeProductId": "",
"HealthierAlternativeProductId": "",
"ImagePath": "http://img.tesco.com/Groceries/pi/716/5010204736716/IDShot_90x90.jpg",
"MaximumPurchaseQuantity": 99,
"Name": "Tesco Bacon   Leek Quiche 400G",
"OfferPromotion": "Any 2 for £4.00",
"OfferValidity": "valid from 2/1/2014 until 21/1/2014",
"OfferLabelImagePath": "http://www.tesco.com/Groceries/UIAssets/I/Sites/Retail/Superstore/Online/Product/pos/2for.png",
"ShelfCategory": "134",
"ShelfCategoryName": "Pies Quiche & Pasties",
"Price": 2.3,
"PriceDescription": "£0.58 each",
"ProductId": "255163145",
"ProductType": "QuantityOnlyProduct",
"UnitPrice": 0.575,
"UnitType": "100g"
}
]
} )
```

My code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Tesco JSONP</title>
</head>
<body>

    <button id="detail">detail</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function detail(data) {
            document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = (data.Products.Name)
        }



            function data() {
            var script_elem = document.createElement('script'),
                url = "http://www.techfortesco.com/groceryapi_b1/restservice.aspx?command=PRODUCTSEARCH&JSONP=detail&searchtext=5010204736716&page=1&sessionkey=123456789"
            script_elem.setAttribute('src', url);
            document.head.appendChild(script_elem);

        }


        document.getElementById('detail').addEventListener('click', data, false);

    </script>


    <div id="name"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

When run I am getting undefined. I'm guessing that my syntax (data.Products.Name) is incorrect. If I try (data.StatusCode) then I get the correct result.

Can someone please advise.

Best wishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data.Products is an array.

You need to specify which element you want to acess in the array.

In this case you only have one element, so the correct syntax would be data.Products[0].name